# Retrofit POST Method with Json data got error code 400 : Bad Request

Tags: android, magento, post, retrofit2, bad-request

I would like to call a POST Method(Magento REST API) in Retrofit with a JSON data(provide JSON as JsonObject). For that, I call as follow from the postman and work fine for me.

[image: POSTMAN]

I have done the android parts as follow,

API INTERFACE

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("seq/restapi/checkpassword")
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
})
Call<Post> savePost(
        @Body JSONObject jsonObject
);}
```

APIUtility class as

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {
}

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://xx.xxxx.xxx.xxx/api/rest/";
public static APIService getAPIService() {

    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
}
```

}

RetrofitClient class as

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

And finally, call the function as follows

```
public void sendPost(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    Log.e("TEST", "******************************************  jsonObject" + jsonObject);
    mAPIService.savePost(jsonObject).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

CallRetrofit API with the POST method with a body.

Comment: Can you share JSON object your sending?

Comment: {"username":"eteteter@ss.com","password":"12345678"} @R2R

Comment: JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
    

    public JSONObject getItem() throws JSONException {

        item.put("usename", "eteteter@ss.com");
        item.put("password", "12345678");
        return item;
    }

and call sendPost(getItem());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to something like this, GsonConverterFactory converts a User object to json itself.

```
public interface APIService {
    @POST("seq/restapi/checkpassword")
    @Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
    })
    Call<Post> savePost(@Body User user);
}
```

This is User Class:

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: How I can call the  sendPost function

Comment: `
User user = new User();
user.setUsername("abcd"); 
user.setPassword("password");

public void sendPost(User user) {

    mAPIService.savePost(user).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
`

Comment: Thanks man , hope its working , after check i will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the `GsonConverterFactory` you've set up for all calls converts your JSONObject to json. That's why your call's body may look quite different than you think. This is the result of `gson.toJson(new JSONObject())`:

```
{ "nameValuePairs": {} }
```

Try changing the object you send to this:

```
public class Credentials {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    ...
}
```

and then update your call

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("seq/restapi/checkpassword")
@Headers({
    "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
})
Call<Post> savePost(
    @Body Credentials credentials
);}
```

To ensure your call is correct, call

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(new Credentials("test_username", "test_password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1.APIInterface.java

```
public interface APIInterface {

    /*Login*/
    @POST("users/login")
    Call<UserResponse> savePost(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> header, @Body UserModel loginRequest);

}
```

2.ApiClient.java

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "baseurl";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

3. API call

   ```
   public void sendPost(JSONObject jsonObject) {

       LoginRequestModel loginRequest = new LoginRequestModel(userName, userPassword);

       Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
       header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

       APIInterface appInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
       System.out.println("Final" + new Gson().toJson(loginRequest));

       Call<LoginResponseModel> call = appInterface.savePost(header, loginRequest);

       call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponseModel>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponseModel> call, Response<UserModel> response) {
               hideProgressDialog();

               if (response.body()!=null) {

               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
   ```

   }
4. Dependencies in Gradle file

   ```
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
   ```

5.User Model

```
public class UserModel {

    @SerializedName("usename")
    @Expose
    String userEmail;

    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    String userPassword;

    public UserModel(String userEmail, String userPassword) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }


}
```

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request,

Comment: @SubinBabu Another way of handing with logging-interceptor.Updated answer