# Retrofit POST Method with WCF services getting error code 400 : Bad Request

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to call a POST Method(REST API) in Retrofit with a JSON data. Postman and Volley library works well, I want to implement it in Retrofit..

I'm looking into it for last two days, not getting any solution..
I have referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904680/retrofit-post-method-with-json-data-got-error-code-400-bad-request) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180957/send-post-request-with-params-using-retrofit/33539088) and much more which look similar but not working out for me..Might be i'm doing something wrong..

These are my inputs[image] and output look like this [image] and my coding part lies here

```
public class Api {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static ApiInterface getClient() {


    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("xxxx/Service1.svc/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    //Creating object for our interface
        ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return api; // return the APIInterface object
}}
```

and interface as

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("UserLogin")
Call<SignUpResponse> registration(@Field("Mobile_no") String mobile,
                                  @Field("Password") String pass,
                                  @Field("RegID") String regId);}
```

and updated Pojo class as

```
public class SignUpResponse {


@SerializedName("UserLoginResult")
@Expose
private UserLoginResult userLoginResult;

public UserLoginResult getUserLoginResult() {
    return userLoginResult;
}

public void setUserLoginResult(UserLoginResult userLoginResult) {
    this.userLoginResult = userLoginResult;
}}class UserLoginResult {

@SerializedName("Email_id")
@Expose
private String emailId;
@SerializedName("First_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("Last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("Mobile_no")
@Expose
private String mobileNo;
@SerializedName("Password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("RegID")
@Expose
private String regID;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}

public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRegID() {
    return regID;
}

public void setRegID(String regID) {
    this.regID = regID;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}}
```

and on MainActivity

```
Api.getClient().registration("xxxNumberhere","rd","222").enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponse> call, Response<SignUpResponse> response) {
            signUpResponsesData = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getUserLoginResult().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("response", t.getStackTrace().toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

and my dependencies are

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

*Following class name and functions are related to my project*

You can be done via,

```
public interface APIService {
    @POST("seq/restapi/checkpassword")
    @Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"
    })
    Call<Post> savePost(@Body User user);
}
```

Then you can send data as,

```
 User user = new User(); 
 user.setUsername("abcd"); 
 user.setPassword("password"); 
 public void sendPost(User user) { 
    mAPIService.savePost(user).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() { 
        @Override public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) { 
            if (response.isSuccessful()) { } 
            } 
        @Override public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) { }

    });
 }
```

You can parse the `error 400`  by,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
RetrofitError mError = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), RetrofitError.class); 
Toast.makeText(context, mError.getMessages().getError().get(0).getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and add RetrofitError  class,

```
public class RetrofitError {
    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private Messages messages;

    public Messages getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(Messages messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

If you have any doubt refer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47904680/6299045). Happy coding... Feel free to ask, if any.
NB:  Add the POJO

```
    public class Example {

@SerializedName("UserLoginResult")
@Expose
private UserLoginResult userLoginResult;

public UserLoginResult getUserLoginResult() {
return userLoginResult;
}

public void setUserLoginResult(UserLoginResult userLoginResult) {
this.userLoginResult = userLoginResult;
}

}
```

--------UserLoginResult
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

```
public class UserLoginResult {

@SerializedName("Email_id")
@Expose
private String emailId;
@SerializedName("First_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("Last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("Mobile_no")
@Expose
private String mobileNo;
@SerializedName("Password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("RegID")
@Expose
private String regID;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;

public String getEmailId() {
return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getMobileNo() {
return mobileNo;
}

public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public String getRegID() {
return regID;
}

public void setRegID(String regID) {
this.regID = regID;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

}
```

Comment: i have already mentioned your link above you can check out..then also i have tried again now,not working..i think some other issue with json parsing

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://xxxx/UserLogin}

Comment: Is it Magento API?. Can you parse the error message

Comment: in your case result was json data without list ,and here it is inside a list,thats the difference,hope you getting my point.

Comment: Its not problem you can add the array before the list, Any way you can parse the error

Comment: I update my answer with error parsing code , please check and find the error

Comment: it is a Rest Api,

Comment: I update my answer with error parsing code , please check and find the error

Comment: Add RetrofitError  class as mentioned in answer

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=xxxx/UserLogin} id Retrofit error ,not the data parsing error

Comment: this error  persist now sorry if iam disturbing you ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1/28418787

Comment: Please create POJO using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, I think your parsing POJO is incorrect

Comment: i have changed Json as per this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31108452/7894033

Comment: Y it's not working, you create the pojo with JSON Schema , else add the responce to your question , iwill make the POJO

Comment: i have used that link to make POJO, but still error occurs.

Comment: Text me the response

Comment: {
    "UserLoginResult": {
        "Email_id": "qasacga@hap.com",
        "First_name": "rahul",
        "Last_name": "devasni",
        "Message": "Successfully Logged in..",
        "Mobile_no": "8291782221",
        "Password": "rd",
        "RegID": "222",
        "Status": "1"
    }
}

Comment: i have updated POJO and same error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind Help @Subin Babu

### Changes that i have did on my project

1)Added a POJO class as same name as parameter

```
public class User {

public String getMobile_no() {
    return Mobile_no;
}

public void setMobile_no(String mobile_no) {
    Mobile_no = mobile_no;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}

public String getRegID() {
    return RegID;
}

public void setRegID(String regID) {
    RegID = regID;
}

private String Mobile_no;
private String Password;
private String RegID;

public User(String Mobile_no,String Password,String RegID)
{
    this.Mobile_no = Mobile_no;
    this.Password = Password;
    this.RegID = RegID;
}}
```

2)Updated ApiInterface class as

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@POST("UserLogin")
Call<SignUpResponse> registration(@Body User body);
}
```

3)Updated MainActivity  class as

```
User user = new User("xxxNumber", "rd", "555");

    Api.getClient().registration(user).enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponse> call, Response<SignUpResponse> response) {
            signUpResponsesData = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SignUpResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

4)All the other remains the same..