# Android retrofit webservice not working

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an online database and I want to send data to my android app using retrofit there is my full code and I don't know why it's not working
[here is my data link](https://codemac.000webhostapp.com/MainCat.php)

**Urls.java**

```
public class Urls {
    public static final String MAIN_URL = "https://codemac.000webhostapp.com/";
}
```

**API.java**

```
public interface API {

    @POST("MainCat.php")
    Call<List<CatResp>> getCat();

}
```

**CatResp.java**

```
public class CatResp {

    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;

    @SerializedName("img")
    public String img;

    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;

    @SerializedName("view")
    public String view;

}
```

**WebService.java**

```
public class WebService {
    private static WebService instance;
    private API api;

    public WebService() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Urls.MAIN_URL)
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

    public static WebService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WebService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public API getApi() {
        return api;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
WebService.getInstance().getApi().getCat().enqueue(new Callback<List<CatResp>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CatResp>> call, Response<List<CatResp>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CatResp>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

where is the problem ? onFailure is called and "Fail" is toasted out

Comment: Please debug your app, the error will be caught in 2 minutes.

Comment: there is no error

Comment: If "Fail" is toasted, how about inspecting the `Throwable t` which seems to hold the reason for the failure?

Comment: Are you sure it is a "POST" method?

Comment: Please refer this question :   https://stackoverflow.com/q/47904680/6299045